# How to fix this TSLint (Object is possibly 'undefined') error for firestore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, tslint

I am using this example below of firesotre from this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions). Hwoever I am getting error **Object is possibly 'undefined'** for the data in data.name. I am pretty sure that I have name in the document. How can I fix this problem please.

```
// Listen for updates to any `user` document.
exports.countNameChanges = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      // Retrieve the current and previous value
      const data = change.after.data();
      const previousData = change.before.data();

      // We'll only update if the name has changed.
      // This is crucial to prevent infinite loops.
      if (data.name == previousData.name) return null;

      // Retrieve the current count of name changes
      let count = data.name_change_count;
      if (!count) {
        count = 0;
      }

      // Then return a promise of a set operation to update the count
      return change.after.ref.set({
        name_change_count: count + 1
      }, {merge: true});
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the TypeScript definition of `change.after.data()`, you will see that the data method is declared to return either undefined or an object.  Since it could return undefined, you need to check for that case before you start accessing properties or methods on it when TypeScript is in strict mode.  And you have to do this even if you're absolutely certain that your document is going to have the named property.

You can either disable strict mode (which I don't recommend - strict mode will protect you from programming mistakes), or you can check `data` and `previousData` before you start using them.

```
const data = change.after.data();
const previousData = change.before.data();
if (data && previousData) {
    // do stuff with them
}
```